# Play! framework upgrade complications

Tags: java, playframework, syntax-error, upgrade

the play framework im currently on in 2.0.4. When i try to upgrade to 2.6.21 using this command:

`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.21")`

I get this error:

`` syntax error near unexpected token `"com.typesafe.play"' ``

can someone point out why this error comes up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a command, it is a setting in the `plugins.sbt` file:

[image]